# Process.Start() totally ignore the environment variables in PATH

Tags: c#

I found that my cmd window prompted by Process.Start() totally ignore my environment variables in PATH. It always said that "xxx is not internal or external commands". I tried run it manually and it worked. Therefore, I am sure the PATH has been set correctly.

I also tried to add the variable explicitly. It still did not work.
This is my code:

```
public static string ExecuteCommandSync(string command)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/K " + command);

        var length = command.Length;

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //Does not work
        procStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("PATH", "C:\\Program Files\\Arm\\Arm Mobile Studio 2021.0");
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        return objException.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `command`?

Comment: PATH is usually defined as both a system and a user environment variable. The obvious issue is if this code isn't running under the same user account as the one you're using to check manually - a detail not present in your question.

Comment: The command is "malioc --version". I don't understand how can I use the different user account to run the code. Doesn't it automatically run my code on my current account?

Comment: You first need to verify of the environment of the process you try to start has the correct PATH (I do see you start `CMD /K` this seems to be OK as first step, while debugging this problem). After that you need to check where the executable `malioc` is (it is expected to be in the current directory or in the directory you specified in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

It is better when you did add the complete description of the error, in stead of "does not work"

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
> range.    at
> System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionaryWrapper.Add(String key,
> String value)    at ConsoleApp88.Program.ExecuteCommandSync(String
> command) in

You cannot add `PATH` because it is already in the list of environment variables.

Solution can be to add the next statement, just before the add:

```
procStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Remove("PATH");
```

Comment: The error is "malioc is is not an internal or external commands". I did not encounter any error from my code. It just cannot recongnize my command.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party on this one. But I came across this problem and found that the command I was trying to run only had a 64 bit version.

So while I could run the command in cmd. If I tried calling cmd from my application it would fail. I didn't realise, but if your app is 32 bit, it will be redirected to the syswow64 folder rather than system32. Even if you explicitly type out the path to the system32 folder it will redirect. And if it doesn't exist in syswow64 it won't work.

And just for clarification, yes, 32 bit apps live in the syswow64 folder and 64 bit live in system32...